# Simultaneous fitting to N datasets in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a single function that I want to fit to a number of different datasets, all with the same number of points. For example, I might want to fit a polynomial to all rows of an image. Is there an efficient and vectorized way of doing this with scipy or other packages, or do I have to resort to a single loop (or use multiprocessing to speed it up a bit)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

```
import numpy as np

# independent variable
x = np.arange(100)

# some sample outputs with random noise
y1 = 3*x**2 + 2*x + 4 + np.random.randn(100)
y2 = x**2 - 4*x + 10 + np.random.randn(100)

# coefficient matrix, where each column corresponds to a term in your function
# this one is simple quadratic polynomial: 1, x, x**2
a = np.vstack((np.ones(100), x, x**2)).T

# result matrix, where each column is one set of outputs
b = np.vstack((y1, y2)).T

solutions, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b)

# each column in solutions is the coefficients of terms
# for the corresponding output
for i, solution in enumerate(zip(*solutions),1):
    print "y%d = %.1f + (%.1f)x + (%.1f)x^2" % ((i,) + solution)


# outputs:
# y1 = 4.4 + (2.0)x + (3.0)x^2
# y2 = 9.8 + (-4.0)x + (1.0)x^2
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this method work only for polynomials, or is it possible to use it with arbitrary functions?

Comment: @astrofrog: You can put any function. e.g. `a = np.vstack((np.exp(x), x)).T` will try to fit `A*e^x + B*x`. Just construct your columns accordingly.